# React Native DeviceEventEmitter keyboardWillShow stopped working

Tags: javascript, react-native

After upgrade to 0.26.0-rc version, on iOs this line:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (e)=>this.updateKeyboardSpace(e));
```

does nothing. When keyboard is open, `updateKeyboardSpace` method is never called.

I'm importing DeviceEventEmitter with this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {DeviceEventEmitter}  from 'react-native';
```

I upgraded from version 0.21 , it was working fine there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[It seems like you can not use this kind of event listener any more.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/516bf7bd94d14600920a3d78fdcf51ea7fe48495/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter.js#L39)
This seems to be [handled by the Keyboard component now](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2525feb37f7b9b3a18625d58e9b9013573c8c129/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/Keyboard.js), which uses native libraries. For [iOS it is defined here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTKeyboardObserver.m#L20), the event names seem to be the same; I couldn't find an Android implementation, though. You would need to test if this works, but for iOS this should do the trick:

```
import {Keyboard}  from 'react-native';
Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (e)=>this.updateKeyboardSpace(e));
```

**EDIT:**

The API explained was internal only. For normal usage, one could use the [callbacks on the ScrollResponder](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee1f37bade91d7db490cb3cb702104f268654ae/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js#L476). [You could use either](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee1f37bade91d7db490cb3cb702104f268654ae/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js#L513-521) `onKeyboardWillShow` and `onKeyboardWillHide`. The ScrollResponder Mixin is used in the [ScrollView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b67d4a20d73f00dd42806b6c275f0982832462ac/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js) and [ListView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/34907c3810bcc2fc1bdcdd599f914ca6c8e9b8a6/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js), so you may use this props there.

[I did a small example on github.](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/react-native-keyboard-shown-example)

Comment: That looks awesome! Will try to test asap!

Comment: great, let me know ;)

Comment: Can't make it work, no matter what i do it throws error: *undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Keyboard.addListener')*. Here is the full message: https://jsfiddle.net/fh3wq8L1/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will try to come up with a working solution soon :)

Comment: This is brilliant! Works on both iOs and Android, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Cherniv which react-native version are you using? Here Keyboard is undefined

Comment: @alex88, I am also getting the undefined error. How did you solve your error?

Comment: @ParthTiwari with my response below, using different events :) They don't fire before but after the keyboard shows but it was fine to me

Answer (score 5):

On android, you can use instead these 2 events:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardWillShow.bind(this))
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardWillHide.bind(this))
```

tested on 0.26.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i know about Android, it doesnt work for me on iOs , sorry that i didnt specify my question

Comment: No problem, it's just that I was searching the answer for android but I haven't found anything until I've searched through RN code and shared here in case anyone else needs it